# Why doesn't Hack infer nullable types?

Tags: type-inference, hacklang

Any specific reason why Hack doesn't automatically infer nullable types? Instead you have to write `?` explicitly. If it used inference instead, wouldn't it be able to check for null for regular PHP programs as well?

For example, this function would have type `bool -> ?string`:

```
function foo($condition) {
  if ($condition) {
    return null;
  else {
    return 'a string';
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking into your question, but something that would help me is: can you phrase the question in a way that is not "why does a feature that I want not exist?" Features don't exist because they were never implemented; that lack of existence doesn't need to be justified.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're asking -- Hack *does* infer nullable types *inside* a function, but doesn't infer *any* types across function boundaries. So the input `$condition` needs to be explicitly annotated as `bool` just like the return type needs to be annotated as `?string`. Are you asking something I don't understand about nullable types in particular, or are you asking more generally why Hack only infers types inside a function but not across function boundaries?

Comment: @JoshWatzman, yes, you're right - this question is meaningless in the context that Hack doesn't do full-program inference. Also, didn't know that Hack infers nullable types inside functions, but that makes sense. Thanks for your answer.